# Fastest way to add a grouping column which divides the result per 4 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

If i have a resultset like this for example (just a list of numbers) :

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

and I would like to add a grouping column so i can group them per 4 like this : 
1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3

(The last one in this examle does not have a forth element, so that is why i cannot use Ntile(3) here.

But I still would like to be able to make a grouping by 4 elements. 
Is this possible in a easy way ( just like NTile(n)) without to write a bunch of logic ?

Thank you in advance,

Greets Jacob

Comment: What is the logic to group? Why dont you have fourth element for 3?

Comment: How about `((ROWNUMBER-1) / 4)+1`?

Comment: It is just a number assigned to the entity in the table, no further logic , it can also be 2,3,5,9,14,17 (in that case the extra column should be 1111,22)

Comment: I try ROWNUMBER / 4, looks like an easy and good solution !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT col,        
       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) - 1) / 4 + 1 AS grp
FROM mytable
```

`grp` is equal to 1 for the first four rows, equal to 2 for the next four, equal to 3 for the next four, etc.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3553/1)

Alternatively, the following can also be used (as suggested by @Jacob Siemaszko):

```
SELECT col,        
       CEILING(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) / 4.0) AS grp
FROM mytable
```

The second query uses *floating point* arithmetic and is likely less efficient compared to the first one.

Comment: Looks OK to me, pretty much the same as my comment.

Comment: @DavidG Well, in fact your comment was better than my answer. `ABS` is not needed. I 've edited my answer.

Comment: Finally your concept was correct but the following worked : 
CEILING(DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Monstercode ASC)/4.0)

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko This is an alternative way of doing it. However, using `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` means you might end up having groups with *more than* 4 members. I'm not sure whether this is what you really want or not.

Comment: Row number/4 simply gives me a complete wrong result

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko I'm afraid I don't understand. I commented on the use of `RANK` vs `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: You are right. I made a mistake impementing ROW_NUMBER, apologies and thank you. Now it works correct

Comment: @JacobSiemaszko i have updated my answer to include the solution you propose.